# Solutions for serving large downloads to prevent interruption from sleep or hibernate?

Tags: php, apache, download, x-sendfile

I'm serving downloads on apache using X-SendFile within PHP. It works great, but the problem I'm anticipating is when users download large >18GB files they may run into issues where their PC's power saving options might interrupt the download. Is there any solution to this besides splitting up the file into pieces and making them download it one by one? Is there download manager software out there I can implement on our server?

Comment: good lord man what kind of files are users downloading that are that big

Comment: It's a software download page, which includes quite large software packages.

Comment: You should look at native applications that can download and install your software, so the user downloads a say 1MB app.  The native application will also be able to keep the computer from going into a full sleep.

Comment: @cmorrissey that's what I'd like to do, but I don't know how to go about doing that for any software that doesn't provide a web installer. That's the question I'm asking. Is there a way to create my own web installers?

Comment: Implementing server-side solutions to client-side problems is a hole with no bottom. My suggestion: Put a note that tells suggests your users turn off sleep/hibernate, link to some instructions, and move on.